# How to correctly compare the substring of array elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a way for each element in 2 arrays to be compared to each other, but just a substring section of each element. My problem is that each element is either a latitude and longitude, and therefore isn't working correctly. The variable a1, is only comparing the latitude value with the variable a2.

funciton

```
   for (i = 0; i < selectedFeature.length; i++) {
      replacer = selectedFeature[i].toString().substring(0, 7)
      selectedFeature[i] = replacer;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < objValues.features.length; i++) {
      replacer1 = objValues.features[i].geometry.coordinates.toString().substring(0, 7)
      objValues.features[i].geometry.coordinates = replacer1
    }




    for (var i = 0; i < objValues.features.length; i++) {
      arr1 = objValues.features[i].geometry.coordinates
      arr2 = selectedFeature

      if (arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) === true) {
        console.log('working')
        selectedFeatureIndex = i;


      }
```

arraysEqual

```
function arraysEqual(a1,a2) {
    /* WARNING: arrays must not contain {objects} or behavior may be undefined */
    return JSON.stringify(a1)==JSON.stringify(a2)
}
```

What i want the code to do. Arr1 is the list of geo points, and arr2 is the point i click on (and will stay the same in this function)

```
arr1 = ["9.1405", "87.3252"]

arr2 = 
["10.1405", "54.3252"]
```

'not found'

```
arr1 = ["10.1405", "54.3252"]

arr2 = 
["10.1405", "54.3252"]
```

'match found'

What's happening is that arr2 is being compared to just the first element in arr1

Comment: Could you clarify what is the output of your code and what's your expected output?

Comment: updated my OP hoping it clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. Please tell us the expected behavior of your code. You need to expose your situation better in the future. But let me tell you some tools to solve what I think is your problem.

you could do  arr1.join('') to get the string representation of the content of the array and compare that with the join of the arr2, if they have the same content the strings will be equal

```
arr1.join('') === arr2.join('')
```

For more information on the join method check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Another way would be to compare `arr1[0] === arr2[0] && arr1[1] === arr2[1]` ....there are a lot of ways of comparing what you want. If this wasn't what you were asking then please develop your question further so we can help you